# How to add validation to user input before they submit

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I wanted to add validation to this input

```
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- Content Here -->
          <!-- Needs Validation -->      
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="" required>
          <a class="btn btn-hercules-font btn-lg btn-block mt-5" href="add_workout_2.php" role="button" id="add_button">+ ADD EXERCISES TO WORKOUT</a>
        </div>
```

I tried using the `required` tag but it doesn't seem to work (I can just click the submit button without inputting any value).

Edit:

```
<form action="add_workout_2.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="" required>
  <a class="btn btn-hercules-font btn-lg btn-block mt-5" type="submit" role="button" id="add_button">+ ADD EXERCISES TO WORKOUT</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: Just a question, why aren't you using the `form` tag, but a div instead?

Comment: Yes I tried it with form, but still doesn't work

Comment: How did you try it? [Like this example?](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required)

Comment: Yes just like that one

Comment: Mind showing your code for the `form` solution?

Comment: Change the anchor tag to a `button` tag, and it will work properly.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos Im using bootstrap that'll remove the styling

Comment: You can style it in your way with buttons too. Check [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the "required" parameter will only trigger, if a valid "submit" event is getting called correctly. Anchor tags has the "type" parameter, but it's not for the same use as an input/button tag. I'd suggest that you convert your anchor tag to a button as follows:

```
<form action="add_workout_2.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" value="" required>
  <button class="btn btn-hercules-font btn-lg btn-block mt-5" type="submit" role="button" id="add_button">+ ADD EXERCISES TO WORKOUT</button>
</form>
```

Then you'll get the wanted result. If you don't want the styling of the button, you can work around that with styling. For future reference, you don't need to add "value="" to the input tag for having an empty tag :-)

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<form action="add_workout_2.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required>
  <input class="btn btn-hercules-font btn-lg btn-block mt-5" type="submit" role="button" id="add_button" value="+ ADD EXERCISES TO WORKOU">
</form>
```